# The role of ecto.create vs ecto.migrate

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm learning Elixir/Phoenix Framework and want to learn how to deploy to a host where I'm not allowed to create additional DB's. Most tutorials instruct that I run `mix ecto.create` to initialize it, but it seems to want to create new DB's. To simulate the host settings, I've tried to create a DB of my own with a pre-made user and then I ran `mix ecto.migrate` to initialize it. It looks fine:

`$ mix ecto.migrate
Compiling 12 files (.ex)
Generated phoenix0 app`

And after that `mix phoenix.server` starts and all seems well. My question: is this enough to run a Phoenix app or should I do something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ecto.create` is just a convenience to quickly create the database(s) when creating a new app or using an app for the first time on a system. You don't need to run it and you can safely ignore that step in the tutorials if the database already exists. If `ecto.migrate` ran the migrations and you didn't get any errors, you're good.